# Get all suburb results for specified postcode using Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

We're using the Google Places autocomplete API feature and finding that our use case isn't working as expected.

In Australia, it is common for a postcode to have many suburbs attached to it. 
 When searching by postcode 2300:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=2300&types=(regions)&components=country:au&key=blah

We only get back one result, Bar Beach.  But instead, there are many suburbs that belong to postcode 2300, as can be seen here:

http://auspost.com.au/postcode/2300

Ideally we'd like the user experience to be that typing 2300 returns all the suburbs associated so that the user can pick the exact one, especially as they all have different bounding boxes.

Is this possible with the Googe Places Autocomplete API?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. The Places API autocomplete matches text 2300 which is a postal code and returns only one result of type postal code. It cannot match 2300 with any feature of type suburb in order to return it as a suggestion, because 2300 is related postal code, but doesn't appear as a part of suburb name.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help on this one @xomena, appreciate your insights.